# How to type in the redundant symbols in Simplified Chinese keyboard layout on MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I consider buying a new MacBook, but just found that the Simplified Chinese keyboard layout option has been added to the new model.

However, as far as the picture goes, it seems there is no difference between the Simplified Chinese and US English with regards to the basic functionality. The picture below is from [Apple Store China](https://www.apple.com/cn/macbook-pro/):

[image]

The only difference is some redundant symbols on backtick, number 4, 6, and two braces, and comma and period (and caps lock is another key but I understand that it is for switching languages easily).

However, I don't understand how you can type in these symbols. How can you type in these characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two sets of symbols are supposed to reflect how the keyboard behaves differently when the input source is set to Simplified Chinese Pinyin and when it is switched back to US via Caps Lock.

Even without the new keyboard, Pinyin input should work that way in Sierra, where the [ ] keys, for example, now produce 【 】.

The new keyboard is also available in the US online store.

Comment: I see. Acually I don't now if it works that way as mine is US-English.

Comment: @Blaszard yes it works that way, even on US-English keyboards. To try it, switch the language to Simplified Chinese and type "[" and "]". It will produce “【” and “】”。